# Phrase Request: Bank account statement, name for payee/charger

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to think of the appropriate word for someone that charges you or that you pay.

If you have a bank statement, what would you name the column that contains the name of people you paid money to or charged you?

Does anyone have any idea what that is?

---

An example statement:

```
Your suggested word | Value
-------------------------------
Dave                | +£10
WalMart             | -£14.99
WalMart             | +£14.99   (an example of a refund)
PC World            | +£99.99
```

Comment: A statement doesn't show to whom *you* paid money, just where the funds from this account went: *payee* is exactly right for that.

Comment: It does show who you paid, e.g. it shows I paid £50 to Walmart (-50) and that a Dave paid me £10 (+10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar thread over on [this forum](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst6396_What-to-call-those-involved-in-financial-transactions-.aspx). The general consensus appears to be "Transactor", meaning someone who participates in a [financial] transaction. "Party" and "Principal" were also mentioned.

Comment: Are you certain that the general consensus on that forum was that "Transactor" was the best choice? Also, it said that  "major players, like the owners or stockholders or those who have direct monetary stakes are principals. If they are merely representatives, like attorneys or brokers, use parties e.g. attorneys identify their respective clients as principals to the transaction they are negotiating." This is different than a banking statement; it is more like corporate finance, no?

Answer (score 4):

Someone you paid money to is a "payee". Someone who paid you money is a "payor". As this column in your example can be either, you might put "Payor/Payee". I just checked my bank statements and they label this column "Description". I checked my last credit card bill and it has no label over the column. I suppose you could put something like "Other party but that seems a little awkward.

Comment: You seem to have left off the closing quote mark on the phrase  “Other party but that seems a little awkward”

Comment: I meant: "Other party", but that seems a little awkward.

Answer (score 3):

I just went to look at my own bank account statement, and that column is in fact labeled *Payee,* for both my debits and credits.

Answer (score 3):

Though *payee* is common, consider *recipient* since it makes it clear where the money went.

Comment: "recipient" doesn't fit the bill because the column sometimes shows "sender" - So "Sender/Recipient" or "Payer/Payee"